# Calculating the average word length

Tags: java, average, mean

I am a java beginner with very weak understanding of java. To my already working code which already calculates the number of words in a sentence, total number of characters of a sentence and the total number of characters for each word, I would like to add another function.

**I would like to add a piece of code which calculates the average of word length, for example if I type in 'hey hi cat dog i', the output would be 2.4. (Because the total number of characters for this sentence is 12, divided by the number of words (5 words) gives the average of 2.4).**

Underneath there is my piece of code I'm working on and this is what I created based on many tutorials, but they all teach the average for numbers, not word lengths. My thinking is that my code should firstly count the sum of characters for each words (word.length) and then divide it by the sum of words (sentence.length). But it seems not to work. **Can you please help me to correct this piece of code?**

```
 { 
//prints out average word length
int length = wordcount / word.length ;
sum =  sum + word.length / sentence length; //this counts the sum of characters of words       and divides them by the number of words to calculate the average
System.out.println("The average word length is " + sum);} //outputs the sum calculated above


 {
```

Underneath there is my full code to help you understand better what I mean. Thank you for all your help!

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //This adds a scaner/text window to the program.
        while(true)
        { // have created infinite loop.
            System.out.print("Enter your text or enter 'quit' to finish the program: ");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();
            if(sentence.equals("quit"))
            { // if enterd value is 'quit' than it comes out of loop
                break;
            }
            else
            {   //else if 'quit' wasn't typed it, the program displays whats underneath.

                System.out.println("You have entered: "
                        + sentence); // to print what the user has entered in the text window/scanner.
                System.out.println("The total number of characters is " + sentence.length()
                        + "."); // to print the total number of characters
                System.out.println("This piece of text has " + countWords(sentence)
                        + " words."); //this method counts the number of words in the entered sentence.


                String[] words =
                        sentence.split(" "); // to get the individual words, splits them when the free space (" ") is found.

                int maxWordLength = 0;
                int wordLength = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                {

                    wordLength = words[i].length();
                    if(wordLength > maxWordLength)
                    {       //This piece of code is an array which counts the number of words with the same number of characters.
                        maxWordLength = wordLength;
                    }
                }
                int[] intArray = new int[maxWordLength + 1];
                for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                {
                    intArray[words[i].length()]++;
                }
                for(int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.printf("There are " + "%d word(s) of length %d<\n>", intArray[i], i);
                }
                System.out.println("The numbers of characters for each word:");  //word.length method counts the number of characters for each word.
                for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(words[i] + " = " + words[i].length() + " characters");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    {
        //prints out average word length
        int length = wordcount / world.length;
        sum = sum + word.length / sentence
        length; //this counts the sum of characters of words and divides them by the number of words to calculate the average
        System.out.println("The average word length is " + sum);
    } //outputs the sum calculated above


    {
        in.close();
    }

    private static int countWords(String str)
    { //this piece of code splits the words when the space (" ") is found and prints out the length of words.
        String words[] = str.split(" ");
        int count = words.length;
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are all these brackets for, this is so confusing. You have no method signature for your averaging method

Comment: Do you know what helps? Properly indented and formatted code with consistent bracket placement. Your code doesn't work because they aren't closing the right statement blocks. This is evident after I've reformatted your code in IntelliJ IDEA (I just tossed it in and pressed reformat, so if your code was complete here, then that should be an exact replica of it).

Comment: I really apologize about confusing brackets, I kept on adding them to get rid of the errors suggesting me to add them. Thank you  Zhuinden for spending time on formatting my code and thank you Trust, I just spent some time on trying to add appropriate method signature!

Comment: @Mat luckily, the reformatting didn't take a lot of time, because IntelliJ IDEA's formatting is really smart once you configure it properly. I'm using the following setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649971/java-8-formatting-lambda-with-newlines-and-indentation

Answer (score 2):

Use the split method.
Here is an example:

```
//returns the average word length of input string s
//the method is of double type since it will likely not return an integer
double avgWordLength(String s){

   String delims=",;. ";//this contains all the characters that will be used to split the string (notice there is a blank space)

   //now we split the string into several substrings called "tokens"
   String[] tokens = s.split(delims);

   int total=0;//stores the total number of characters in words;

   for(int i=0; i<tokens.length(); i++){

      total += tokens[i].length(); //adds the length of the word to the total

   }

   double avg = total/tokens.length();

   return avg;

}
```

And there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to call something like:

```
public static double getAverageCharLength(String str) {
    String words[] = str.split(" ");
    int numWords = words.length;
    int totalCharacters = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
         totalCharacters = totalCharacters + words[i].length();

    return totalCharacters/numWords;
}
```

I can't really tell you where you're going wrong because I can't understand the jumble that is your code. But this is the logic you should follow.

**Note:** This will not calculate correctly the average word length **if** your words contain special characters like apostrophes. I'm not sure if you need to look out for that in your case but if you do, look into regular expressions to specify what characters to ignore and using `String` methods like `contains()`.

Also note that you have no method signatures for the following two methods you're trying to define:

```
{
    //prints out average word length
    int length = wordcount / world.length;
    sum = sum + word.length / sentence
    length; //this counts the sum of characters of words and divides them by the number of words to calculate the average
    System.out.println("The average word length is " + sum);
} //outputs the sum calculated above


{
    in.close();
}
```

Maybe try going over the Java syntax in the oracle docs if you're unsure on how to go about writing these methods correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
String input = "hello Alpha this is bravo";
        String[] strArray = input.split(" ");
        float totalChars = 0;
        for(String s : strArray){
            totalChars += s.length();
        }
        float words = strArray.length;
        float averageWordLength = (float)(totalChars/words);
        System.out.println(averageWordLength);
```