# Words frequency in percentage java

Tags: java

I have to make a program that does the words frequency from a linkedlist and outputs the result like this : 
word, number of occurrences, frequency in percentage

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Link {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    File file = new File("words.txt");

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        String words;

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            words = sc.next();
            words = words.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
            words = words.toLowerCase();
            words = words.trim();
            list.add(words);
        }

        sc.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<String, Integer> frequency = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String count : list) {
        if (frequency.containsKey(count)) {
            frequency.put(count, frequency.get(count) + 1);
        } else {
            frequency.put(count, 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(frequency);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("\n" + "Duration: " + (end - start) + " ms");
    }
}
```

Output : {a=1, ab=3, abbc=1, asd=2, xyz=1}

What I don't know is how to do the frequency in percentage and ignore the words shorter than 2 caracters. For example "a=1" should be ignored.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: although you are starting with Java - try to **not** stuff all your code into main. A function/method should do **one** thing, not two, three, or 10.  To answer you question: do you really need Stackoverflow to introduce the concept of if/then/else to you? For example: if (word has less than 2 characters), then don't add it to the word list?!

Comment: Should the words shorter than 2 characters be ignored in the frequency as well? I mean: "a aa" should output {aa=0.5} or {a=1.0} ?

Comment: word shorter than 2 characters  would not count them as a word or you will count them but will not put in the output.?

Answer (score 4):

First, introduce a `double` variable to keep track of the total number of occurences. E.g.

```
double total = 0;
```

Next is to filter out any `String` with `length() < 2`. You can already do this before adding them to your `LinkedList`.

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    words = sc.next();
    words = words.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    words = words.toLowerCase();
    words = words.trim();
    if (words.length() >= 2) list.add(words); //Filter out strings < 2 chars
}
```

Now, when going through your `String`s we should increase the `total` variable by `1` for each occurence like so;

```
for (String count : list) {
    if (frequency.containsKey(count)) {
        frequency.put(count, frequency.get(count) + 1);
    } else {
        frequency.put(count, 1);
    }
    total++; //Increase total number of occurences
}
```

We can then use `System.out.printf()` to print it all out nicely.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: frequency.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("String: %s \t Occurences: %d \t Percentage: %.2f%%%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), entry.getValue()/total*100);
}
```

[image: Example]

Note that this will not look nice (the `printf` statement) once you are working with large `String`s, or have a ton of occurences. So optionally you could do the following given that `maxLength` contains the largest `length()` of any `String` in your list and `occLength` contains the amount of digits of the largest occurence.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: frequency.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("String: %" + maxLength + "s  Occurences: %" + occLength + "d  Percentage: %.2f%%%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), entry.getValue()/total*100);
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Seems like you could remove the first loop and filter the words as you count them. For a small case its doesn't make much difference but saves having to traverse the entire list of words twice.

Comment: That's certainly true. Undoubtedly the code (in many aspects) could be designed nicer and more efficient. This was just a straightforward answer to his question.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore strings with size less than 2 while adding to map step and maintain a legal words counter for calculating percentage.

```
int legalWords = 0;
for (String count: list) {
    if (count.size() >= 2) {
        if (frequency.containsKey(count)) {
            frequency.put(count, frequency.get(count) + 1);
        } else {
            frequency.put(count, 1);
        }
        legalWords++;
    }
}
for (Map.Entry < String, String > entry: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue() + " " + (entry.getValue() / (double) legalWords) * 100.0 + "%");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** As the OP question does not provide us with details, let's assume that we will count words of one character but we will not output them.

*Seperate your logic from your main class:*

```
class WordStatistics {
    private String word;
    private long occurrences;
    private float frequency;

    public WordStatistics(String word){
        this.word=word;
    }

    public WordStatistics calculateOccurrences(List<String> words) {
        this.occurrences = words.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.equalsIgnoreCase(this.word)).count();
        return this;
   }

    public WordStatistics calculateFrequency(List<String> words) {
        this.frequency = (float) this.occurrences / words.size() * 100;
        return this;
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

**Explanation:**

*Considering this list of words:*

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Java", "C++", "R", "php", "Java",
        "C", "Java", "C#", "C#","Java","R");
```

*Count occurrences of `word` in `words` using java 8 Streams API:*

```
   words.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.equalsIgnoreCase(word)).count();
```

*Calculate word's frequency percentage:*

```
  frequency = (float) occurrences / words.size() * 100;
```

*Setting up your words' statistics(Occurrences+Frequency):*

```
List<WordStatistics> wordsStatistics = new LinkedList<WordStatistics>();

    words.stream()
            .distinct()
            .forEach(
                    word -> wordsStatistics.add(new WordStatistics(word)
                            .calculateOccurrences(words)
                            .calculateFrequency(words)));
```

*Output result with ignorance of words of one character:*

```
    wordsStatistics
            .stream()
            .filter(word -> word.getWord().length() > 1)
            .forEach(
                    word -> System.out.printf("Word : %s \t"
                            + "Occurences : %d \t"
                            + "Frequency : %.2f%% \t\n", word.getWord(),
                            word.getOccurrences(), word.getFrequency()));
```

*Output:*

```
Word : C#       Occurences : 2  Frequency : 18.18%  
Word : Java     Occurences : 4  Frequency : 36.36%  
Word : C++      Occurences : 1  Frequency : 9.09%   
Word : php      Occurences : 1  Frequency : 9.09%
```

Comment: All that chaining and lambda makes for some unpleasant indentation. I find it hard to believe that this is really how these tools are intended to be used.

Comment: When Combining multiple functionality like *remove* duplicated words and *loop* through list and set up a list of `WordStatistics` all togethet, it seems to be a little bit long. @bhspencer

Comment: Maybe this could be improved by following some code formatting standards for stream chaining and lambdas but as it stands I find it pretty much unreadable.

Comment: It seems like some prefer to put each link in the chain at the same level of indentation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649971/java-8-formatting-lambda-with-newlines-and-indentation

Comment: Thanks for letting know that. But downvoting my answer for this kind of reason `unreadble` is not an option. Instead you can help me improve my answer. Anyway, I will make it more obvious. @bhspencer

Comment: I think down voting an answer for a solution that is barely readable is an option. Creating code that can be read and maintained by others is just as an important part of programming as solving the task at hand. I will happily remove my down vote if you can produce a solution that would get past a code review.

Comment: @bhspencer I got what you mean and you are absolutely right. Code must be readable and obvious for people. So How about now (answer edited)?

Comment: That is much cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toSet())
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toList())` ??? Why not just use [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)?

Comment: @vandale That would be to get a list without duplicated words from the initial list.

Comment: 1) you don't need to convert it back to a list if your going to be doing stream operations on it and are never going to use the intermediate  list. 2)getting rid of duplicates is precisely what distinct does.

Comment: @vandale  woow that is really powerful. I didn't know that. Thanks so much. (I will edit my answer).

Comment: are you browsing all words every time you want the occurence of any single word?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you help me improve my answer? I don't think it is that bad to get downvote.

Comment: Mr Hovercraft Full Of Eels please can you help me review my code? sorry for wasting your time. (I got some downvotes and i don't know why). @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple data structure to make this easier.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class WordCounter {

    private int wordTotal;
    private Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();

    public WordCounter(List<String> words) {

        wordTotal = words.size();

        for (String word : words) {
            wordCount.put(word, wordCount.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Double> getPercentageByWord() {

        return wordCount.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
                        e -> getPercentage(e.getValue())));
    }

    private double getPercentage(double count) {
        return (count / wordTotal) * 100;
    }
}
```

Here's a test that uses it.

```
@Test
public void testWordCount() {

    List<String> words = Arrays.asList("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");

    WordCounter counter = new WordCounter(words);
    Map<String, Double> results = counter.getPercentageByWord();

    assertThat(results).hasSize(6);
    assertThat(results).containsEntry("a", 40.0);
    assertThat(results).containsEntry("b", 20.0);
    assertThat(results).containsEntry("c", 10.0);
    assertThat(results).containsEntry("d", 10.0);
    assertThat(results).containsEntry("e", 10.0);
    assertThat(results).containsEntry("f", 10.0);
}
```