# Words occurrence in linked list java

Tags: java

I have to do word occurrences in a linked list but without storing the words into a Map. I'm only allowed to use the linked list. The output: words, occurrence, percentage. Can someone help please ?

```
public class Linkedlist {

    private LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    public void readFile() {

        File file = new File("words.txt");

        try {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

            String words;

            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                words = sc.next();
                words = words.toLowerCase();
                Collections.sort(list);

                if (words.length() >= 2) {
                    if (list.contains(words)) {


                }
            }

            sc.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showList() {
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Linkedlist abc = new Linkedlist();

        abc.readFile();
        abc.showList();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Than output: words, occurence, percentage"*--how "occurence" and "percentage" is supposed to be calculated?

Comment: @Sasha see his earlier question

Comment: You almost did the job by sorting the list. Now, comparing an element to the previous can tell you how many time each word appears, its occurrence etc.

Comment: What exactly you wish to calculate?

Comment: In other words : keep a reference to the previous word. If current word != previous word, then the previous word will not reappear anymore. Hence you can tell howmany time it appeared.

Comment: @LalitRao For example I have these words in my text file : car cat dog car. The output schould be car, 2 , 50% ...... cat, 1, 25%...... dog, 1, 25%.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053286/words-frequency-in-percentage-java/30056406#30056406) .

Comment: Your code is all messed up dude! I think you need to clear your basics first.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
    Collections.sort(words);
    String last = null;
    int n = 0;
    for (String w : words) {
            if (w.equals(last)) {
                n++;
            } else {
                if (last != null) {
                    System.out.printf("%s %d %.1f%%%n", last,  n, 100.0 * n / words.size());
                }
                last = w;
                n = 1;
            }
    }
    System.out.printf("%s %d %.1f%%%n", last,  n, 100.0 * n / words.size());
```

Comment: Could you please explain the above logic?

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        String words;          
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            words = sc.next().toLowerCase();
            list.add(words);  
         } 
        Scanner sc1=new Scanner(file);
        int i=0;
        while (sc1.hasNext()) {
             words = sc1.next().toLowerCase();              
            double count=0;
         while(i<list.size()){
            if(list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(words)){
                  count++;
                   i++;
            }

            else                    
                 break;             
        }
        if(count !=0)
         System.out.println(words+" "+(Double)count/list.size());

        }

        sc.close();
        sc1.close();
    }
```

> > Modify the try  block as above  Hope the code is self explanatory.

Ouput:

```
  car 0.5
  van 0.25
  bus 0.25
  [car, car, van, bus]
```

Comment: Is anyhow we can avoid 2 while loop in the above code logic?

Comment: One while loop helps in storing values and another one for calculating the percentage.  While loop runs for n elements so having 2 while loop will run with the $O(n) complexity