# Format java code in java 8 style

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to format my `java` code using `Ctrl+Sft+F` in  Eclipse Neon IDE. 
I want to get my code formatted in java 8 style.. like below

```
     persons.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getAge() > 30)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But it formatted it in a single line(like nelow), I've to manually format it in java 8 style that is really a headache.

```
persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > 30).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is there any setting option in eclipse to get it formatted in `java 8` style.

Comment: There is no "java 8 style". There are only preferences, either yours or your teams.

Comment: Possible duplidate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649971/java-8-formatting-lambda-with-newlines-and-indentation